# SSRS. How to turn on/off rows grouping using parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, grouping

I have report where is ability to hide/show grouped rows by clicking `+` / `-`.
In `Group Properties` > `Visibility` tab I've checked `Display can be toggled by this report item:` and selected `col1`.

Here is start view on report.

[image: grouped rows]

After clicking `+` It show hidden rows as following:

[image: Expanded group]

I need to create parameter with ability to turn on / off grouping at all.

For example, If user set paramter *Don't group* It should show report without `+` / `-` as normally. And If parameter *Use grouping* is selected - It should be as shown in images above (with ability to hide / show rows).

I need to use an expression something like:
`=IFF(@parameter.Value = useGrouping, Check: "Display can be toggled by this report item:", else uncheck)`

With code above I just trying to explain how It should work, but I can't get success with syntax. Have you ideas?

Comment: Just a thought while I look into this: You could recreate the same matrix without grouping and place it directly underneath that one, and set visibility based on the parameter.  That would certainly be a quick fix for now. Alternatively, add the ungrouped rows below the grouped ones and do the same thing with the row visibility.

Comment: Use your parameter in an expression on the Row Group's visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can set group expressions to make them based on the parameters.

Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrishays/dynamic-grouping) for detailed article on dynamic grouping.